# Difficulty with jar files and accessing event class

Tags: jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnpbB.png)

I am having A hard time with the Jar files and am wondering what I am doing wrong, maybe I put them in the wrong spot

Tried to access the event class in the jar file but it says source not found

Comment: Please don't post images for text content. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help people help you.